# Forgotten password e-mail not sent: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: magento2, customer, forgot-password

After upgrading from Magento **2.3.4** to **2.4.3-p3**, when I ask Magento to send the "Forgot password" email, I get instead of the expected template: `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`.

After investigations, I observed that the `rp_token` retrieved in the method : `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry::retrieveSecureData` does not look like what was generated here: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php:666` but more like a string of badly encoded characters.

example:

`getUniqueHash` generated: `kVbfH1PAMkAs1drINkJ60zoy8yBHh5aw`

Returned from `retrieveSecureData` method : `.�Q��p~U%��<�A�D���H�6�`

Despite my research I have not been able to find a valid solution. Has anyone encountered or seen a similar problem?

Comment: I think that isn't mate, because after magento update rpToken after get response from retrieveSecureData

Comment: When Magento saves the token, it is the one generated previously but, after saving, Magento will re-fetch the customer's information from the database and it is at the time of this retrieval that it is not decrypted correctly and returns me .�Q��p~U%��<�A�D���H�6�

Comment: after reading the code, I confusing now, How can they save the token :(

Comment: I think this is similar your issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35663

Comment: Yup, but I try this solution not working because I encrypt my encrypted string

Comment: Did you check beforeSave and afterLoad of the customer.php?

Comment: Ok, on `afterLoad` method `$rpToken`, Magento try to decrypt the clear value

Comment: Try to debug vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php:236 (populateCustomerWithSecureData)

Comment: In `populateCustomerWithSecureData`, `$customerSecure->getRpToken()` return clear value and set this value in `$customerModel`, Magento save and encrypt data, and we reload our customer but, in `afterLoad` data is not encrypted and we decrypt our clear value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140910/discussion-between-hoanghieu-and-kallard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with a blank magento 2.4.3-p3 and understood and solved my problem.

The encrypted `rp_token` is added in the `customer_entity` table AND the old (maybe) unencrypted token was stored in `customer_entity_varchar`.

When Magento retrieved the customer data, it found an encrypted token BUT, when it retrieved in the same action the model attributes in `MagentoEav\ModelEntity\AbstractEntity::_loadModelAttributes` on line 1062, Magento found the unencrypted token in the `customer_entity_varchar` table which caused problems because it was trying to decrypt a cleartext value which caused my problem.

To fix this problem, I removed the `rp_token` from the `customer_entity_varchar` table and it works again. I did the test by creating a dummy token and performed the password reset request action again and I was getting the error again.

Thank you @HoangHieu for the time you spent to help me